# User response with yes in Ansible playbook

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a problem with my ansible playbook. Normally i use the console to upgrade a program.
After the dependency check i have to answer with yes. I checked the [Shell documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html?highlight=shell),

Now i scripted that with Ansible, and the task is pending because no user can do an interaction.
As example this is the part of my testplaybook which is not working.

```
# Uninstall tree
  - name: uninstall
    shell: yum remove tree
```

My question is now how can i submit a decision, as example yes or no in my playbook.

ps: I know i can set the yum module to the state: absent but this is basd on the yum module.
pps: No i do not want to send the -y  paramenter in the shell. This does not solve all my problems

Answer (score 1):

For Yum, use the Yum module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html

However, your answer can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html